# How to fill a cell array of strings with the indices of its cells in another array of strings?

Tags: string, matlab, cell-array, indices

I'm trying to fill a cell array of strings `attributes` (764x1 cell) with the indices of each of its cells in another cell array of strings `data` (269x1) if the cell content (string) is found in `data`. I wrote the following code to do so:

```
for i=1:length(attributes)
    for j=1:length(data)
        attributes{i,1}=strfind(data{j,1}, attributes{i,1});
    end
end
```

I'm getting empty cells:

[image: inedx]

Answer (score 0):

Your are overriding `attributes` in the first iteration for internal loop:

Example:

```
data{1} = 'aabbcc';
data{2} = 'bbaacc';
data{3} = 'ccaabb';

attributes{1} = 'aa';
attributes{2} = 'bb';
attributes{3} = 'cc';

for i = 1:length(attributes)
    for j = 1:length(data)
        attributes{i} = strfind(data{j}, attributes{i});
    end
end
```

After first iteration of internal loop `j = 1`:
`attributes{1} = 1`

After first iteration of internal loop `j = 2`:
`attributes{1} = []`

Because `attributes{1} = 1` from previous iteration.
`attributes{i} = strfind(data{j}, attributes{i});` equivalent to:
`attributes{1} = strfind(data{2}, 1);`
and 1 is not found in data{2}.

What you probably meant do, is something like the following code:

```
data{1} = 'aabbcc';
data{2} = 'bbaacc';
data{3} = 'ccaabb';

attributes{1} = 'aa';
attributes{2} = 'bb';
attributes{3} = 'cc';

%Initialize new 2D cell array.
attrib_indexes = cell(length(attributes), length(data));

for i = 1:length(attributes)
    for j = 1:length(data)
        %Store result in attrib_indexes{i, j} instead of attributes.
        attrib_indexes{i, j} = strfind(data{j}, attributes{i});
    end
end
```

I recommend you to learn using the debugger, it's easier than posting a question in Stack Overflow...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [one of the variants of `strfind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html?searchHighlight=strfind#btvz3p5-1) to look in all `data` at once:

```
att_ind = cell(length(attributes),length(data)); % Initialize a result cell array
for k = 1:length(attributes)
    att_ind(k,:) = strfind(data, attributes{k});
end
```

this will result in a `length(attributes)`-by-`length(data)` cell array such that 
`att_ind(k,n)` is all the instances of `attributes{k}` in `data{n}`. If there is no such instances then `att_ind(k,n)` is empty cell.